# Do I always have to make one Sequelize model file per table?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

I feel like I've progressed a bit far from day 0 in learning node-express + mysql + sequelize, BUT, I'm still confused like if I'm still on the right path.

I'm designing a User role models, one user has only one role model.

Questions are:

1. do I always have to make one sequelize model file per table?
2. I read about normalizing database tables, so I'm thinking not making a `role_id` column in my **Users** table, and instead make a new table. Is this right?

For instance, I have tables in my scheme design (not sure if it's the correct term, I drew my db design on https://dbdiagram.io/) namely:

1. Users table
2. Roles table
3. UserRoles table

**USERS** has id(pk), full_name, email.

**ROLES** has id(pk), description, user_id(foreign key????)

**USERROLES** has id(pk), user_id, role_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes this will be very useful because:

   - you'll always be sure where to find a certain model - just find a file with that name in models folder.
   - you;ll be ale to automatically register all models at once simply by reading all files in a models folder and register them in sequelize
2. Yes you need a join-table (many-to-many relationship) to link users and roles.

Comment: Thank you! One more question. I constructed my question details above with confusion. I realized that like I mentioned, User has ONLY ONE Role (one-to-one???), so in this case, do I still need `USERROLES` table? Or can I just add a column in the `ROLES` table named `user_id`?

Comment: If it is a 1:0-1 or 1:M, no “joining” table is required. M:M is what requires the joining (UserRoles).

Comment: If you are 100% sure that in a future won't be more then one role per a user then you can simply add role_id to a user model

Comment: Thanks both. But what if I can only make `ROLES` table have a new columned for fk named `user_id`? And not the other way around? I can't seem to make Sequelize model do that. it's not adding `role_id` to the `USERS` table, but it does add `user_id` to the `ROLES` table.

Comment: Create a new question with model definitions and this issue with FK and we will look at it

Comment: Okay, I will surely post a new one in a moment. I need to clear some stuff really before I proceed with other models. Thanks!